# Removing material scraped onto car paintwork from plastic wingmirror

Tags: cleaning, car, paint

What is the quickest way to remove material scraped onto a car's paintwork from another car's plastic wingmirror? Removing even a small amount is so far taking a large amount of elbow grease.

Comment: Washing-up liquid and water with a lot of elbow grease. It comes off, but it is just taking an enormous amount of time.

Comment: Buffing machines do a lot of the elbow grease for you. You could use a power drill with a buffing attachment.

Answer (score 4):

Standard automotive repair practice is to use [polishing compound](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009JKGJ2) for light-to-moderate finish removal, and [rubbing compound](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009V3ZE) for rapid, heavy removal of material; these can be found at most auto supply stores and even supermarkets, as well as online.

Be aware you're removing a bit of the auto's finish, as well as the transferred paint:

1. Do not remove too much paint, i.e. go down to primer, or major repainting will be needed.
2. After cleanup, apply a good paste [wax](http://forums.nicoclub.com/wax-after-rubbing-compound-t484795.html) to protect the area where paint was removed and to restore gloss.